# CComVariant for boolean?

Tags: com, atl, variant, bstr

I am writing an ATL library (I'm very new at this) and I have a function that I want to return `BSTR` and `VARIANT_BOOL`. My function looks like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP myClass::GetResult(BSTR* myString, VARIANT_BOOL* contains) {
    std::pair<BSTR, bool> result = outQ.deQ();
    CComBSTR stringOut(result.first);
    CComVariant cont(result.second);
    *myString= stringOut.Detach();
    // this doesn't work, and I honestly don't know how to make it work
    //*contains = cont.Detach(contains);
    return S_OK;
}
```

I want to call this function from C# code. I had function working like this only with the `BSTR` and the C# code got the correct values and all. I just don't know how to return `VARIANT_BOOL` because there is no `CComVariant_BOOL` or whatsoever.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you feel you need `CComVariant` here? Just to `*contains = result.second ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;` And `*myString = result.first;`, for that matter.

Comment: I want to `Detach` it the same way I am detaching the BSTR

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I told you I'm very new at this and I know I sound really naïve with these comments, but should it not be detached so I can transfer the ownership?

Comment: Do you want to call a specific function regardless of whether there's a reason to or whether it's suitable, or do you want to solve the problem at hand in the most direct way possible?

Comment: Okay I will try doing it the way you suggested and will get back with the result. Thanks

Comment: A simple boolean doesn't involve any resource management. There's nothing to own, and therefore nothing to transfer ownership of. `BSTR` is a different matter. Your current code makes a copy of the `BSTR` returned by `deQ`, and transfers ownership of that copy over to the caller. It's not clear to me what happens to the original, who owns it now; I suspect it's being leaked.

Comment: Oh that made it clear thanks. My current `BSTR` is part of a pair that I am creating inside the function, should it not get destroyed as the function returns and it goes out of scope? It isn't `BSTR*` what I am getting in the `pair`.

Comment: `BSTR` is simply a typedef for `wchar_t*` - a dumb pointer. It cannot magically destroy itself. Hence the need for smart wrappers like `CComBSTR`.

Comment: `VARIANT_BOOL` is an integer type - they don't have ownership

Comment: @M.M Yeah Igor explained it well, thx

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could you make an answer out of this I want to select it as the answer of the question :)